# getting playlist of stations for internet radio application in android

Tags: android, internet-radio

I want to develop an internet radio application in android.I am new to this application.
I am planning to get the list of station and put them in an xml file in sdcard and provide that in a listview so that when one item is get selected that station will start playing.The xml file should be updated if any new station is added.
How can i get the list of stations.
Can anybody please suggest me the way to proceed in detail....

Comment: You are asking how to get a list of internet radio stations?

Comment: yes,is there any way to get the such list

Answer (score 2):

Shoutcast is not giving out api keys anymore, but you have streamfinder (http://www.streamfinder.com/internet-radio-api/) and dirble.com (http://dirble.com/api)

I'm the one behind Dirble, so if you want help you can ask me.

Comment: How can I stream radio on flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Try using shoutcast api from [partner request form](http://www.shoutcast.com/partner_request_form) [API documentation](http://dev.aol.com/SHOUTcast/documentation)